# In Service Fabric, does SetupEntryPoint execute on all nodes?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

In a Service Fabric cluster of **10** nodes, I deploy my application which have an `InstanceCount` set to **1**.

If I specify the `SetupEntryPoint` element so a certain startup script will be executed before my service starts, will it execute only in the **1** node that currently hosts my application? Or will automatically execute on all of the **10** possible cluster nodes (that is, after the app was deployed to those nodes).

In other words, I want my script to execute on all of the cluster's nodes, not only in the node that currently runs my app.

Is it possible? (using `SetupEntryPoint`?).

Answer (score 0):

The SetupEntryPoint script is only executed before the service is created. Therefore, it is not necessarily executed on all nodes. In other words, if you create a single instance, it is only run once on this particular node. If the service is moved to another node, it is run again on the new node.

If you need to run scripts on all nodes, maybe a [custom script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) for the VMSS is an option. This is not specific to Service Fabric. It can be integrated using an ARM template.